# Basic authentication on IIS 7.5

Tags: windows, iis-7.5

I'm trying to run a simple ASP.NET application with basic authentication on an IIS server. Interestingly, the authentication works fine on almost all servers except my production server. When I deploy the application on that machine, it keeps prompting me over and over for the credentials. Unfortunately, it is a lab machine that I don't have access to and I'm not able to view the logs either.

It's an IIS 7.5 server running on a Windows 2008 VM server I guess, and the content folder (where the default app is pointing to) is on shared with us (we have write access to that folder and that's how we are deploying our applications).

Outside authentication settings on the server, what other things could be causing the issue? Please advise.

Comment: Yeah I guess so. But I need to provide specific details to the lab folks if I request their help in debugging. That's why I'm curious to know if there is anything outside authentication settings that could cause this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably this is a access permission to resources used by the web application. 
The reason you see this repeatedly login prompt is that the account doesn't have the needed permissions.

First you have to determine if you are using impersonation or not.
If you do impersonate, the authenticated accounts need the necessary permissions.
If you don't impersonate, the application pool account needs the necessary permissions.

So what's the needed permissions?

Well, that could be a lot of things, and we don't know the details of your application.
Do you connect to a database?
Then you have to make sure that current account context has the right permissions to connect to the DB.

Do you read images/files from disk?
Then you have to make sure that current account context has the right permissions to access those resources.

If it is file resources that you are accessing, I would recommend you to use Fiddler and determine which path(s) you'll need to address. It will tell you by those 404 errors.

EDIT: Make sure that your app pool account has the needed permissions for this DLL you mention. Where does it fetch this list from? Is it static in the DLL? Where's this DLL located?
Please also check the event logs on the server for any related errors at the time you try to logon.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Magnus. The application is very simple and it uses an internal proprietary DLL to fetch a list. In all other machines, if I don't have permissions to access that internal system, I'm able to get to the page and then I see an error message on the screen where the list is supposed to appear. However, in this server, all I'm getting is repeated authentication boxes. If  I cancel the auth request (probably because anonymous logon is enabled), I'm able to get to the application with the expected error message (related to the internal component). There is no I/O DB or file!

Comment: Forgot to mention that when I cancel, the user id is not the same as the id I provided (it uses the default app pool id I guess).